# GAS - Script execution time too long / Workaround?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that takes more than 5 minutes to execute. So it will be aborted after 5 minutes with the information that the execution time is too long.

Now I am looking for a solution to handle this. In the following example I would like to interrupt when `var = i` has reached a value of 300 and then continue with `i = 301`. Is this an option for a workaround? If so, how has the code to be adapted?

```
var xy = 1100;
for (var = i; i<= xy; i++){
{
do_some_stuff();
}
}
```

In practice my code is the following....and the loop is starting with `for(var i = 3; i <= lastrow +1; i++)` lastrow has a value of 1500.

```
    function Create_geodata()
 {

  var Geodata = getSheetById(1702838837);
  var Geojson_Data = getSheetById(1515926044);
  var Control_Panel = getSheetById(1102907697);

  Geodata.getRange('I4').setValue('Yes');

  var Hyperlink_Geodata = Control_Panel.getRange('O18').getValue();
  var document_missing_ID = Control_Panel.getRange('O24').getValue();
  var Umap_Hyperlink = Control_Panel.getRange('L20').getValue();
  var umap_zoom = Control_Panel.getRange('N22').getValue();
  var Own_ID_Sort_Setting = Control_Panel.getRange('O30').getValue();
  var Own_ID_Sort = Control_Panel.getRange('M32').getValue();
  var Threshold_Altitude = Control_Panel.getRange('N28').getValue();
  var Automatic_Altitude_Removal = Control_Panel.getRange('O26').getValue();

  var Cat_A = Control_Panel.getRange('C36').getValue();
  var Cat_B = Control_Panel.getRange('C38').getValue();
  var Cat_C = Control_Panel.getRange('C40').getValue();

  RESET_Geodata(); //Clear data before proceed

  if (Own_ID_Sort_Setting)
  {standard_sort_column = Own_ID_Sort}
  else
  {standard_sort_column = "name"}


  var data = Geojson_Data.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col1 = data[0].indexOf(standard_sort_column) + 1;
  var col2 = data[0].indexOf('coordinates') + 1;
  var col3 = data[0].indexOf('name') + 1;
  var col4 = data[0].indexOf('description') + 1;

  var col1_Char = columnToLetter(col1); //last row of column where sort-criteria is located
  var col2_Char = columnToLetter(col2);
  var col3_Char = columnToLetter(col3);
  var col4_Char = columnToLetter(col4);
  var lastrow_col1 = Geojson_Data.getRange(col1_Char + ':' + col1_Char).getValues();
  lastrow_col1 = lastrow_col1.filter(String).length;

  var lastrow = Geojson_Data.getLastRow();//last row of complete sheet
  var lc = Geojson_Data.getLastColumn(); //last column
  var lc_Char = columnToLetter(lc);

  var dc = 0;
  Geojson_Data.getRange('N1').setValue(col1);


  if (!document_missing_ID)

  {
   for(var t = 2; t <= lastrow; t++)
   {

   if (Geojson_Data.getRange(t,col1).getValue() == "")
   {
    Geojson_Data.deleteRow(t);

   }
   }  
   }

  else
  {
     for(var t = 2; t <= lastrow; t++)
   {

   if (Geojson_Data.getRange(t,col1).getValue() == "")
   {
    dc++;
    var formattedNumber = ("000" + dc).slice(-4);
    Geojson_Data.getRange(t,col1).setValue('ZZ_' + formattedNumber);

   }
   }
  }

   Geojson_Data.getRange('A2:' + lc_Char + lastrow).sort(col1);

   Geojson_Data.getRange(col1_Char + 2 + ':' + col1_Char + lastrow).copyTo(Geodata.getRange('A3:A' + lastrow),{contentsOnly: true});
   Geojson_Data.getRange(col2_Char + 2 + ':' + col2_Char + lastrow).copyTo(Geodata.getRange('F3:F' + lastrow),{contentsOnly: true});
   Geojson_Data.getRange(col3_Char + 2 + ':' + col3_Char + lastrow).copyTo(Geodata.getRange('B3:B' + lastrow),{contentsOnly: true});
   Geojson_Data.getRange(col4_Char + 2 + ':' + col4_Char + lastrow).copyTo(Geodata.getRange('D3:D' + lastrow),{contentsOnly: true});

  var geodata_sorted = '';
  var route_length = 0;

   for(var i = 3; i <= lastrow +1; i++)
   {
   var pr = 0;
   var fl = false;
   var distance_neighbour_points = 0;
   var Ar = Geodata.getRange('F' + i).getValue();
   Ar = Ar.split(',');
   var Ar_Anz = Ar.length - 1;
   for(var b = 0; b <= Ar_Anz; b=b+2)
   {
   if ((Ar_Anz - b) != 0)
   {
   var E_Lat = Ar[b];
   var E_Lon = Ar[b + 1];
   if (fl)
   {
   var A_Lat = Ar[b - 2];
   var A_Lon = Ar[b - 1];

   distance_neighbour_points = distVincenty(A_Lat, A_Lon, E_Lat, E_Lon);

   if (Automatic_Altitude_Removal && (distance_neighbour_points > Threshold_Altitude))
   {
     b++;
     E_Lat = Ar[b];
     E_Lon = Ar[b + 1];
     A_Lat = Ar[b - 3];
     A_Lon = Ar[b - 2];
   }

    route_length = route_length + distVincenty(A_Lat, A_Lon, E_Lat, E_Lon);
   }
   pr++;
   fl = true;
   }
   geodata_sorted = geodata_sorted + E_Lat + ',' + E_Lon;
   if ((Ar_Anz - b) < 2)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   geodata_sorted = geodata_sorted + ',';
   }
     if ((Ar_Anz - b) < 2)
   {
   pr = parseInt(pr / 2) * 2 + 1;
   var Ay = geodata_sorted.split(',');
   var Geo_Mitte_Lon = Ay[pr - 1];
   var Geo_Mitte_Lat = Ay[pr];
   var googlemaps = 'https://maps.google.com/?q=' + Geo_Mitte_Lat + ',' + Geo_Mitte_Lon;
   var umap = 'https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/de' + '/map/' + Umap_Hyperlink + '#' + umap_zoom + '/' + Geo_Mitte_Lat + '/' + Geo_Mitte_Lon;
   Geodata.getRange(i, 3).setValue(route_length / 1000);
   Geodata.getRange(i, 6).setValue(geodata_sorted);
   Geodata.getRange(i, 7).setValue(googlemaps);
   Geodata.getRange(i, 8).setValue(umap);  

   //Verlinkung
   if (Hyperlink_Geodata)
   {
   var displayName1 = Geodata.getRange(i,1).getValue();
   var displayName2 = Geodata.getRange(i,2).getValue();
   Geodata.getRange(i,1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK(\"' + googlemaps + '\";\"' + displayName1 + '\")');
   Geodata.getRange(i,2).setFormula('=HYPERLINK(\"' + umap + '\";\"' + displayName2 + '\")');
   }

   geodata_sorted = '';
   route_length = 0;
   } 
   }

   //Set categories Cat_A,B,C...
   var description_content = Geodata.getRange(i,4).getValue();

   var regExpA = new RegExp('/*' + Cat_A, 'gi');
   var regExpB = new RegExp('/*' + Cat_B, 'gi');
   var regExpC = new RegExp('/*' + Cat_C, 'gi');

   var compareA = regExpA(description_content);
   var compareB = regExpB(description_content);
   var compareC = regExpC(description_content);

   if (compareC == Cat_C) Geodata.getRange(i,5).setValue(Cat_C);
   if (compareB == Cat_B) Geodata.getRange(i,5).setValue(Cat_B);
   if (compareA == Cat_A) Geodata.getRange(i,5).setValue(Cat_A);

   }

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveSheet(Geodata);

  Geodata.getRange('I4').setValue('No');
  }
```

Comment: Might I recommend this solution instead? - https://script.gs/bypass-script-execution-timeout-programmatically/

Comment: Hello! It seems like your problem is with the code itself. Consider optimizing the code to avoid repetition and use multiple functions to avoid the 30 seconds per function limit on apps script. Also, if you want to manipulate huge amounts of data, it's better to do so with a separate application that only uploads the finished result to sheets.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Meanwhile I have learned how to optimize the code and to save the variables in arrays. Now it takes just a few seconds.